Searching for Illustrated, fantasy book from as early as 1960's maybe earlier. wyverns, dragons, airships beautiful watercolor like illustrations
Main Ideas are - Illustrated book, Setting is fantasy European medieval-ish, wyvern frozen in ice, dragon in chains in a cave, airships powered by stones that emit some kind of gas, two kids, village terrorized. They go on a journey for some reason, the actual dragon is not the bad guy its the wyvern who has escaped from the vertical ice wall. Written at least prior to 1970's.

Might it be one of Joe Nigg's marvelous illustrated books? He had at least one that was a collection of stories.

Also asked here but with no answer so far.

Dragonworld
Dragonworld is a 1970 fantasy book by Byron Preiss and Michael Reaves, illustrated by Joseph Zucker. It has wyverns and a chained ancient dragon, with the villain being a dragon/wyvern halfbreed. The back cover text is:

Somewhere beyond the northern mists lies a land where dreams live and dragons are real. This is the tale of the twilight of the dragons, of two nations plunged into war by a tragic misunderstanding, of a shy dreamer's incredible voyage of peace to a long-forgotten land where nightmares are born. A magnificent creation, a sweeping epic of high fantasy set in a richly imagined world, vividly brought to life with over eighty pages of stunning illustrations by Joseph Zucker.




This makes it a duplicate of this question.
